# How to detect if the browser has support for webauthn

Tags: webauthn

Webauthn is currently only supported in a limited number of devices https://caniuse.com/#search=webauthn.

In JavaScript I want to be able to detect if the users browser has support before offering them an sign-in or join form.

Checking for navigator.credentials seems to work but is it the right way to check for this support?

```
if(!navigator.credentials) {
  alert('fail');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By checking [`navigator.credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/credentials) you're checking that the browser supports [Credentials Management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API), which is more than just WebAuthn.

Credential Management API so far supports 3 type of credentials, [`FederatedCredential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FederatedCredential), [`PasswordCredential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential) and [`PublicKeyCredential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential).

WebAuthn is built on top of the `PublicKeyCredential` interface. See https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#iface-pkcredential.

So what you need is:

```
 if (typeof(PublicKeyCredential) == "undefined") {
   alert('fail');
 }
```

That's why when you ask the browser to create a "WebAuthn credential", you need to specify the public key type: `navigator.credentials.create({ "publicKey": { ... } })`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/create#Parameters.